# Problems while getting relative paths of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am reading in a different machine a file. Therefore, I need to access to the full path of the file. So I tried to use pythons Pathlib module:

```
a_path = '/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'
home = str(Path.home())
a_path = str(home) + str(a_path)
```

Apparently, the above code return me the full path. However, when I read it I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/home/user'/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'"
```

How can I fix the above error? maybe in the concatenation I am getting problems.

Comment: If you're using `pathlib.Path`, use `/` to join paths. E.g. `a_path = Path.home() / a_path`. Not sure if that's the issue here, though. There appear to be extra single quotes in your path?

Comment: When are you getting the error? On which code?

Comment: I could not reproduce your error, can you please provide more info?

Comment: yes I am getting extra quotes in my path @Nathan. I also Tried the `/` and i am getting a Posix which I cant read

Comment: Please update the question with the full code you're running to get the error, including reading the file in. You'll also need to let us know about the contents of (the relevant portion of) your home directory. I can't see how the code you posted above could lead to the path you have in the error (not only do the paths differ, but the extra quotes should be there).

Comment: I updated the question @Nathan

Comment: There's still no code for reading the file in - what line of code do you run to get the error? Maybe try `a_path = Path.home() / 'dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'` then `print(a_path.is_file())`. Is there actually a file at `$HOME/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt` on your system?

Comment: The problem is with how you're actually setting `a_path`, it's adding the extra quotes. The code you've posted won't do that.

Comment: The title is misleading, you're trying to get an absolute path, not a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This uses [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) which joins two paths together

```
import os
import pathlib
a_path = 'dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'
home = str(pathlib.Path.home())
print(os.path.join(home, a_path))
#/home/user/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt
```

Comment: If I do not have the home directory how can I get it? Remeber I want to install this in different machines

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: still having the extra quote

Comment: what does `print(home)` outputs for you

Comment: The problem is with how he's setting `a_path`, not `home` or how he's joining them.

Comment: Also can you run ls on the file path you mentioned and provide the output as well

Comment: I was adding an extra `/`

Comment: Then you don't need that extra `/` if you use os.path.join to join the paths

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to paste the string together.

`''.join([str(Path.home()), 'path\\t.txt'])`

Comment: i am still getting the extra quote, its the same issue

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with how he's joining things, it's with how he sets `a_path`.

Comment: I am not even getting that extra quote as the OP mentioned the output. ( I am on windows right now)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `'/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'` is an absolute path. If you want it to be a relative path (which seems to be the case) you should use `'dir1/subdir1/sample.txt'`, so without a leading `/`.

Using the pathlib library this then becomes very easy

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> a_path = "dir1/subdir1/sample.txt"
>>> a_path = Path.home() / a_path
>>> print(a_path)
/home/pareto/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt
```

Again, **make sure you are not using absolute paths**. Otherwise you would get the following

```
>>> print(Path.home() / "/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt")
/dir1/subdir1/sample.txt
```